# Правильное добавление элемента в массив Python

Tags: python, массивы

Есть у меня переменная, которую я инкремирую (так же говорят?), а потом добавляю в массив. Делаю это несколько раз, в цикле.

В питон я пришёл из си и привык, что если я не говорю, что передаю элемент по ссылке, то я не передаю его по ссылке.
Сейчас же, в питоне, все элементы моего списка всегда одинаковы и соответствуют этой переменной.

В документации копался, признаю, что плохо, ответ должен быть не глубоко, но будет круто, если кто-то ответит быстрее, чем я докопаюсь.

Часть кода:

```
array = []
for i in range(3):
    array.append(Pose)
    Pose.pos.x += (width * 0.001)
```

На выходе получаю `array` состоящих из 3-х одинаковых элементов

З.Ы. "Pose" - это так надо ,это не я не грамотный.

Comment: Это не три одинаковых элемента, это один и тот же элемент, добавленный три раза.

Comment: @Igor , да я понимаю. Но я добавляю элемент, потом изменяю и добавляю снова. И ожидаю, что первый элемент при это не изменится. Списки же не только из вручную дабавленных элементов создаются? Мне же не нужно 9469628823 запасных переменных делать, я же не знаю заранее размер массива.

Answer (score 1):

Михаил, если на листке бумаги написать три разных строчки, то он не превратиться в три листка бумаги, это будет всё тот же один лист бумаги.

Чтобы работать с тремя разными объектами, нужно как-то создать три разных объекта.

Как это сделать - зависит от того, что из себя представляет ваш `Pose`.

В питоне с большой буквы записывают название класса, что несколько обескураживает, поскольку те действия, которые вы пытаетесь делать с `Pose` как-то не очень осмысленны для класса.

Возможно, вам нужно сначала инстанцировать отдельные экземпляры класса, и работать уже с ними:

```
array = []
for i in range(3):
    p = Pose()
    array.append(p)
    p.pos.x += (width * 0.001)
```

Если же у вас `Pose` вопреки заглавной букве итак уже является инстанцированным экземпляром класса, то вам нужно как-то скопировать его, или инстанцировать ещё два отдельных экземпляра. Чтобы в точности сказать, как это лучше сделать, мне нужно видеть определение класса, экземпляром которого является `Pose`. Если вы приведёте его, я смогу лучше вам помочь.